# How to add value from a iframe using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a sample code:
in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>index</title>  
</head>  
<body>
<input type="text" value="" name="test" id="text_input">
<iframe src="iframe.html">
</body> 
</html>
```

And iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>iframe</title>  
<script>
function getValue(text) {
    document.getElementById('text_input').value = text;
}
</script>
</head>  
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="getValue('test');">Click</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

When click on a tag, value "text" can not be passed on `from iframe to index.html`, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parent` to get parent window of `iframe`. Try this

```
function getValue(text) {
    parent.document.getElementById('text_input').value = text;
}
```